# Java Stream: List of objects to HashMap without duplicates

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to convert a `List` to `Map` without duplicates using a stream but I can't achieve it.

I can do it using a simple loop like this:

```
List<PropertyOwnerCommunityAddress> propertyOwnerCommunityAddresses = getPropertyOwnerAsList();

Map<Community, List<Address>> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for (PropertyOwnerCommunityAddress poco : propertyOwnerCommunityAddresses) {

    if (!hashMap.containsKey(poco.getCommunity())) {
        List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(poco.getAddress());
        hashMap.put(poco.getCommunity(), list);
    } else {
        hashMap.get(poco.getCommunity()).add(poco.getAddress());
    }
}
```

but when I try to use a stream, my mind crash.

I have to say the `PropertyOwnerCommunityAddress` contains two object more: `Community` and `Address` and the goal of all of this is for each community save the addresses in a `key:value` pair without duplicate the `Community` object.

Anyone can help me? Thank you!

Comment: Your entire loop body can be replaced with `hashMap.computeIfAbsent(poco.getCommunity(), key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(poco.getAddress());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can have multiple `Address`es per `Community` you can't use the `toMap()` collector, but you need to use `groupingBy()`:

```
Map<Community, List<Address>> map = propertyOwnerCommunityAddresses.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        PropertyOwnerCommunityAddress::getCommunity,
        Collectors.mapping(
            PropertyOwnerCommunityAddress::getAddress, 
            Collectors.toList())
        )
    );
```

Depending on your personal preference, this can look messy and maybe more complicated than the simple for-loop, which can also be optimized:

```
for(PropertyOwnerCommunityAddress poco : propertyOwnerCommunityAddresses) {
    hashMap.computeIfAbsent(poco.getCommunity(), c -> new ArrayList<>()).add(poco.getAddress());
}
```

Depending if you only want to have unique addresses you may want to use `Set`, so change the `Collectors.toList()` to `Collectors.toSet()` or when you stay with your for-loop change the definition of `hashMap` to `Map<Community, Set<Address>>` and in the loop exchange `new ArrayList<>()` with `new HashSet<>()`

Comment: Thank you! The first stream is exaclty I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use

- `groupingBy` to get the `Community` as key
- `mapping` to get the `Address` as list

```
Map<Community, List<Address>>  hashMap = propertyOwnerCommunityAddresses.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PropertyOwnerCommunityAddress::getCommunity,
                    Collectors.mapping(PropertyOwnerCommunityAddress::getAddress, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is as valid as @Lino. Thank you for you post suggestions as well